The top 5 highest values PowerBI measure
I need help with a measure that should always show the top 5 highest values. However, when I select a country, cities from that country are added, resulting in more than 5 values. Any ideas why this is happening?
I've tried to use such DAX formula but to no avail. Please find screenshots attached below.
Top 5 Cities of the Highest Cost of Living =
CALCULATE(
[Sum Cost of Living],
KEEPFILTERS(
TOPN(
5,
ALL('Address'[City]), -- Clear any filters on City
[Sum Cost of Living]
)
),
REMOVEFILTERS('Address'[Country]) -- Ensure country filters don't affect the top 5 cities
)



You can apply a Top N filter directly to the City column on the table visual. See below:


It worked! But is it possible to do the same but only with the dax formula? Like without using the help of filter?

The measures do not filter the visual without having a filter on the visual. You could create a Calculated Table to filter the Top 5. However, it will not update based on slicers and will only update on report refresh.
